# My PHP While(true) automatically stopped in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I have tested this script in my localhost a whole day and it's still working. But in cpanel this script is stopped automatically

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $run = TRUE;
    $nowtime = date("Y-m-d H:i");

    while($run){
        $stop = GetSetting("Stop");
        $time = date("Y-m-d H:i");
        if($stop){
            $run = FALSE; // stopped when setting changed
            continue;
        }
        if($time != $nowtime){
            log_message("debug","Still Running On ".$time); //checking if it still running every minute
        }
        $nowtime = $time;
    }
```

what do you think happened? What is possible cases that made it stop? Is it about memory? or server configuration? or other possibility?

Comment: Did you check the log?
What does that "getSetting" function do (by the way. Functions should start with lower case letters)?
Did you check if the time limit changed at all?
What exactly are you trying to archive with this script?

Comment: GetSetting is function for check database, it purpose is to stop the while when setting is 1, so when Stop == 1 then while stopped. I made it to create daemon system that run continiously to create some jobs that can't handle by cron jobs. Time limit is okay, No "Maximum execution" error and "memory limit" error in log

Comment: You are not checking stop for === 1. Also you could also just use "break;" instead if what you did in your `if ($stop)`.
How are you running this script exactly? PHPCLI? Apache?
This whole thing sounds more like a purpose problem to me. PHP is not designed for stuff like that. You should switch to something different like, I don't know, a bash script at least or something closer to the system like C to create such a deamon.
Either way: I can not think of anything that could not be handled by a cronjob that runs every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very easily by running PHP from the 'command line'. Here is a sample script to show 'proof of concept'. I run PHP 5.3.18 on windows XP (oi!, stop laffin').

I show the captured output.

Script:

```
<?php
    // P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql\Q22710846.php
    //
    // run this from the command line - press ctrl-c to kill the task.

    set_time_limit(0);
    $run = TRUE;
    $nowtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $debug = false; // set true to stop after 10
    $loopCount = 10;

    if (!$debug) {
       echo "press ctrl-c to end the task as it will forever!\n\n";
    }
    while(($debug && $loopCount) || (!$debug && $run)) { // will run forever...

        $nowtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        echo 'The time now is, beep, beep, beep : ', $nowtime, "\n";

        // generate a random delay of between 1 and 10 seconds
        $delay = mt_rand(1, 10);
        echo 'waiting for : ', $delay, " seconds\n";
        sleep($delay);

        // log_message("debug","Still Running On ".$time); //checking if it still running every minute

        if ($debug) {
          $loopCount--;
        }

    }
?>
```

Sample output...

```
P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql>php Q22710846.php
press ctrl-c to end the task as it will forever!

The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:03
waiting for : 8 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:11
waiting for : 7 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:18
waiting for : 6 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:24
waiting for : 6 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:30
waiting for : 5 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:35
waiting for : 8 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:43
waiting for : 8 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:51
waiting for : 2 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:19:53
waiting for : 8 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:20:01
waiting for : 1 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:20:02
waiting for : 3 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:20:05
waiting for : 7 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:20:12
waiting for : 9 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:20:21
waiting for : 9 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:20:30
waiting for : 8 seconds
The time now is, beep, beep, beep : 2014-04-02 11:20:38
waiting for : 1 seconds
^C
P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql>
```

Answer (score -1):

it is because of php.ini and php config in your server . you must chang the php time limit 
by ini_set(); to do this

Comment: This answer is based on nothing. There is not even the slightest evidence for such a thesis.
Also this is a very bad idea, because then every script would be executed with no time limitation which could consult in mayor performance issues and crashing servers.