# Creating php system_daemon in cpanel with whm root access

Tags: php, linux, daemon, cpanel, whm

Based on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710846/my-php-whiletrue-automatically-stopped-in-cpanel), i think i have to create a daemon that runs in linux system. Now i don't know how to get started, can you help me for this? i'm windows based, i want to create daemon that run witn PHP like described by [system_daemon](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/01/09/create-daemons-in-php/). i have root access of whm, and now what must i do? Please i'am stuck. Thank youu

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that requires a constantly running script? Normally, if you want something to run at regular intervals then you use a 'cron' job. On windows look at the 'Task scheduler' in the control panel.

Comment: i want create a services that insert to a database every x second with irregular times. and the interval will always changing after i insert a new row to database. and it's running a whole day

Comment: Looking at your previous question, which i assume, was a 'proof of concept'. I would expect for someone to mention running PHP via the CLI (Command Line Interface') and just running it as a background task. On windows use the run and enter 'cmd' to access the 'command line'. There are various tutorials available about setting it up. There is normally a separate php.ini file and you would need to remove the maximum execution time. You may be able to do this at the script level. use the 'sleep' command to pause the task

Comment: Article of using PHP from the 'command line': **http://www.sitepoint.com/php-command-line-1/**. Here is a 'so' question about creating a PHP script as a service for later: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952500/setting-a-php-script-as-a-windows-service**

Comment: I have posted an answer to your previous question. Give it a go an see what you think.

Comment: i am sorry @RyanVincent but i have tested in localhost (windows 7 with AppServ) and it's working a whole day. The problem is in cPanel. in cpanel its stop misteriously without error and logs

Comment: You do not run it via the web server. You run it from the command line. Read the instructions on how to run PHP from the command line. 'Command Line PHP' has nothing to do with cpanel. Look at the sample output i gave in your previous question. I ran PHP from the CLI. To access the CLI in windows use the 'start menu' then enter 'cmd' to get the 'windows shell' prompt. enter:  php --version press return. if PHP CLI is installed properly then you will get some sensible information.

Comment: 'cpanel'? 'windows 7'? i am not familiar with cpanel on windows server. I have met it on linux web hosting sites. Therefore i do not know if it provides access to the 'command line' version of PHP.